# ios swift - auto layout programatically to subview

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm adding a prompt to purchase the full version of the app by displaying a uiview to the user; however, I'm having issues settings constraints programatically as to not have the issue shown in the image below on the iPhone 6 plus.

I'm doing:

```
 let purchasePopUp = PromptPurchase.instanceFromNib() as! PromptPurchase
            //purchasePopUp.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


            purchasePopUp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

           // let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: purchasePopUp, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: purchasePopUp, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
           // let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: purchasePopUp, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: purchasePopUp, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            //view.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
             view.addConstraints([trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint])

            view.addSubview(purchasePopUp)
```

And it's still only taking up the same space.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: It's not obvious what your issue is, but I presume you want the view to fill the area of the parent view. Firstly are the constraints active. I cannot remember if they are by default. So check that. Secondly, for simplicity, I would recommend switching to the visual format language or to the newer iOS8 anchors as a method for defining constraints. I've found anchors to be a really simple way to do them. Just remember to activate them.

Comment: That's correct, I want the view to fill the area of the parent view. Constraints are active by default. I will look into anchors immediately. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

With EasyPeasy your code would look like this, give it a try :)

```
import EasyPeasy

if let purchasePopUp = PromptPurchase.instanceFromNib() as? PromptPurchase {
    view.addSubview(purchasePopUp)
    purchasePopUp <- Edges()
}
```

https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy